# Square root of a value defined in a finite field?

Tags: syntax, number-theory, number-representation, finite-fields

I am trying to find the right way to compute the square root of a number defined in a finite field. For example,

```
<< FiniteFields`
In[18]:= Sqrt[GF[17][{8}]]
Out[18]= Sqrt[Subscript[{8}, 17]]
```

Results in an incorrect answer. The correct answer is `5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PowerMod[n, 1/2, f]
```

e.g.

```
PowerMod[8, 1/2, 17]

(* 5 *)
```